# Cannot call View in Asynctask Android, java

Tags: java, android, view, android-asynctask

I am trying to call the view from another class in my Asynctask class but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my AsyncTack

```
private class parseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Integer>> {

    protected List<Integer> doInBackground(String... arg) {
     List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            htmlHelper hh = new htmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
            output = hh.htmlHelper(arg[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return output;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Integer> exe) {

        graph salesView = new graph();
        View chartView = salesView.getView(this);
        chartView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f));
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearview);

        layout.addView(chartView, 0);

    }
}
```

And here is what the activity 'graph' looks like

```
public class graph {

public View getView(Context context) (...etc.)
```

I don't understand why it can't call the view.

Comment: ...the error occurs at the line 'View chartView = salesView.getView(this);'

Comment: View chartView = salesView.getView(this);
In the above code 'this' refers to AsyncTask instance, not the Context. Maybe you wanted to write ParentActivity.this?

Comment: You forgot to post the error/exception you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you intended `graph` to extend `Context` in some way, such as by extending `Activity`, and that `parseSite` is defined inside `graph`, make the following change:

```
View chartView = salesView.getView(graph.this);
```

In the original code, `this` is referring to `parseSite` which does not extend `Context` (and does not refer to `graph` as you probably intend).

As a side note, in typical Java style classes should be named with an upper case letter, i.e. `Graph` not `graph`.

Comment: Ah, I don't have parasite defined within graph. How would you recommend I do that?

Comment: Move the class to graph. You may or may not want to make it `static` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you try to access view from other thread that created it. Usual way is to use `runOnUiThread()`:

```
(activity).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

 //call anything to your View objects

    }
});
```